# KSH prompt being overwritten

Tags: shell, ksh, prompt

I have customised my ksh shell prompt. It is as follows:

```
export PS1=$'\E[31;1m$(date +%H:%M:%S) \E[32;1m${PWD##*/} \E[33;1m$ \E[0m'
```

Sometimes when I press backspace the cursor will jump to the very beginning of the window and overwrite the prompt. I heard this can be a problem with escaping the colours however the examples I have seen online resemble what I have above.

Any idea what can be causing this?

Comment: With what version of ksh, on what operating system? What terminal are you using and what is the value of `$TERM`?

Comment: TERM=vt100, OS is Red Hat Enterprise Linux, and ksh version is 'Version M 1993-12-28'

Comment: What terminal do you use (and on what operating system, if logging in remotely)? The problem may be a mismatch between `$TERM` and the actual terminal (hardware or more likely teminal emulator).